# How often have pitchers earned a win and a save on same day?

Tags: baseball, history

On Sunday 25th April 2015, David Robertson managed a rare feat: he [earned a win and a save on the same (calendar) day](http://www.chicagotribune.com/sports/baseball/whitesox/ct-report-white-sox-royals-spt-0427-20150426-story.html). While the first win technically was [on Friday, according to the box score](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHA/CHA201504240.shtml), for practical purposes he earned a win and a save on the same calendar day.

Has this ever happened before, and if so, how many times and by whom (if it's a reasonable number)?

Comment: When you say "same calendar day" , it seems odd (atleast to me) because Friday and Sunday are Definitely not the same on the calendar , unless that is standard baseball nomenclature. If it is not a standard baseball phrase, then something like "same day as per records" might be a better way to state it.

Comment: I think he was confused, because both games were played on Sunday April 26th, it was a doubleheader due to one game being postponed on Saturday.

Comment: Actually, the first game (the win) was the continuation of Friday's game which was suspended after eight in a tie. Robertson was announced for the ninth so he had to pitch to the first batter (and finished the inning). That occurred Sunday. It was 'officially' Friday as that's how they count resumed suspended games, but it occurred on Sunday.

Comment: Just to be clear - the meaning of 'calendar day' is meant to be that Robertson earned a win and a save on one day as measured from one sunrise to the next (or one midnight to the next). It wasn't considered one schedule day was the distinction I was trying to make.

Comment: It could happen in a "normal" double header, where the closer pitches the ninth, and gets a save in one game, then pitches 1 inning, and is the "pitcher of record" in the other game because his teammates "win" the game when they come bat after his inning.

Comment: It certainly could happen any number of ways - that, or even a game one night going into the next day getting the save after midnight and then the win the next.  I would like to know if it *has* happened, and how frequent it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sunday, May 6, 1917, Bob Groom  got a save in the first game of a doubleheader for the St. Louis Browns over the Chicago White Sox. In the second game he got the win, pitching a no-hitter.

Comment: Well that certainly seems to qualify, though the save wasn't an official stat then, he definitely earned one by the modern definition.

Answer (score 1):

May 28, 2019 Alex Colome, of the White Sox,  got a win in the first game of a double header and the save in the second:

- [Game 1](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHA/CHA201905270.shtml), suspended from May 27 and completed on May 28.
- [Game 2](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHA/CHA201905280.shtml), the regularly scheduled game for May 28.